# Nginx, Gunicorn, Django, Celery(Redis): upstream prematurely closed connection 502 gateway

Tags: django, docker, nginx, redis, celery

I run a setup with docker-compose on linux server. Two days ago I added gunicorn + nginx to the setup. Unfortunately, all rest api endpoints that start celery tasks stopped working (it returns 502 gateway not found).

When I try to send a post form on `calculate shortest path` that starts celery task, 502 gateway returns.

```
Issue:
 Summary
 URL: http://192.168.0.150:8001/tspweb/calculate_shortest_paths/
 Status: 502 Bad Gateway
 Source: Network
 Address: 192.168.0.150:8001
```

Here are the logs from django container and nginx container.

```
tspoptimization | [2018-10-31 07:26:30 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:15)
nginx_1   | 2018/10/31 07:26:30 [error] 8#8: *9 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.0.103, server: localhost, request: "POST /tspweb/calculate_shortest_paths/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://192.168.128.2:8001/tspweb/calculate_shortest_paths/", host: "192.168.0.150:8001", referrer: "http://192.168.0.150:8001/tspweb/warehouse_list.html"
nginx_1   | 192.168.0.103 - - [31/Oct/2018:07:26:30 +0000] "POST /tspweb/calculate_shortest_paths/ HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "http://192.168.0.150:8001/tspweb/warehouse_list.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0 Safari/605.1.15" "-
```

Everything was working perfectly before gunicorn + nginx were added (on local system without those 2 it works perfectly fine). That means that it is not timeout issue.

My suspicion is that the nginx+gunicorn doesn't 'redirect' the POST request from form into celery. I started celery with loggging on to a file and this is the content of the celery log file:

```
root@4fb6e101a85b:/opt/services/djangoapp/src# cat logmato.log
[2018-10-31 07:12:04,400: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to.    redis://redis:6379//
[2018-10-31 07:12:04,409: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2018-10-31 07:12:05,430: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2018-10-31 07:12:05,446: WARNING/MainProcess] /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/fixups/django.py:200:     UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never use this setting in production environments!
 warnings.warn('Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never '
 [2018-10-31 07:12:05,446: INFO/MainProcess] celery@4fb6e101a85b ready.
 [2018-10-31 07:14:07,802: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://redis:6379//
 [2018-10-31 07:14:07,813: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2018-10-31 07:14:08,835: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2018-10-31 07:14:08,853: WARNING/MainProcess]/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/fixups/django.py:200:          UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never use this setting in production environments!
warnings.warn('Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never
2018-10-31 07:14:08,853: INFO/MainProcess] celery@4fb6e101a85b ready.
```

As you can see from the logs, celery workers didn't start a single task that means the problem is not in the celery nor redis, but somewhere in connection between (nginx-gunicorn-django-celery).

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:  # <-- connect to the bridge
      - database_network
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
    expose:
      - "5672"
  django:
    build: .
    restart: always
    container_name: tspoptimization
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/services/djangoapp/src
      - static_volume:/opt/services/djangoapp/src/tspweb/static  # <-- bind the static volume
      - media_volume:/opt/services/djangoapp/src/tspweb/media  # <-- bind the media volume
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    networks:
    - nginx_network
    - database_network
  celery:
    build: .
    command: celery -A tspoptimization worker -l info
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - django
    links:
      - redis
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
     - 8001:80
    volumes:
     - ./config/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
     - static_volume:/opt/services/djangoapp/src/tspweb/static  # <-- bind the static volume
     - media_volume:/opt/services/djangoapp/src/tspweb/media  # <-- bind the media volume
    depends_on:
     - django
    networks:
     - nginx_network
networks:
  nginx_network:
    driver: bridge
  database_network:  # <-- add the bridge
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

Here is the nginx conf:

```
upstream hello_server {
    server django:8001;
}

server {

    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        # everything is passed to Gunicorn

        proxy_pass http://hello_server;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /tspweb/static/ {
        alias /opt/services/djangoapp/src/tspweb/static/;
    }

    location /tspweb/media/ {
        alias /opt/services/djangoapp/src/tspweb/media/;
    }
}
```

my django settings:

```
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://redis:6379'
STATIC_URL = '/tspweb/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)), '/tspweb/static')
MEDIA_URL = '/tspweb/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'tspweb/media')
```

And lastly, the dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6

RUN mkdir -p /opt/services/djangoapp/src
WORKDIR /opt/services/djangoapp/src
ADD . /opt/services/djangoapp/src

EXPOSE 8001
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --no-input
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", ":8001", "tspoptimization.wsgi"]
```

Any help how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this issue alone, so here is the answer:

Redis & Celery must be in the same virtual network created by docker with nginx-network and db-network.

This is the docker-compose file that is working and the tasks are sent properly:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:  # <-- connect to the bridge
      - database_network
  redis:
    image: "redis:latest"
    expose:
      - "5672"
    networks:
      - database_network
      - nginx_network
  django:
    build: .
    restart: always
    container_name: tspoptimization
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/services/djangoapp/src
      - static_volume:/opt/services/djangoapp/src/tspweb/static  # <-- bind the static volume
      - media_volume:/opt/services/djangoapp/src/tspweb/media  # <-- bind the media volume
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    networks:
    - nginx_network
    - database_network
  celery:
    build: .
    command: celery -A tspoptimization worker -l info
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - django
    links:
      - redis
    networks:
      - nginx_network
      - database_network
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
     - 8001:80
    volumes:
     - ./config/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
     - static_volume:/opt/services/djangoapp/src/tspweb/static  # <-- bind the static volume
     - media_volume:/opt/services/djangoapp/src/tspweb/media  # <-- bind the media volume
    depends_on:
     - django
    networks:
     - nginx_network
networks:
  nginx_network:
    driver: bridge
  database_network:  # <-- add the bridge
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

Actually I don't know whether this is the way how this should be handled, but I am not a professional in devops, so at least this work for now.